# How to maintain connection after login with requests to navigate web page

Tags: python, python-requests

I am looking to navigate a webpage after login via requests. My code is successful at logging into the web page but I am unable to access the webpage following login. Here is the procedure I am looking to execute upon:

1. Login to the website
2. Click the "Search" tab
3. Enter text into the search bar that appears following the click

As I said, I have successfully finished step 1 but am having a hard time proceeding with steps 2 and 3. Below is my code:

```
import requests

class ptab:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = '{"userName":"username","password":"pword"}'
        self.params = (
    ('cacheFix', '1615866146331'),
)
        self.cookies = {
    '_gid': 'GA1.2.505039707.1615866090',
    '_gat_SiteSpecificT': '1',
    '_gat_RollupT': '1',
    '_gat_GSA_ENOR0': '1',
    '_ga': 'GA1.2.767718179.1615866090',
    '_gat_UA-21265023-12': '1',
    '_4c_': 'lZJNj5swEIb%2FysrnOMHYGJNb%2BqEqUluttNuVekLGOMEKwZbxQrOr%2FPeOE0j22HJh5hnP6xl439HY6A6tCSeZ4JwkCSV0gQ761KP1O%2FKmjq8BrRGFQkbzAhPNCGYqY1iKiuGMc7qrqBQqFWiB%2FkStlHKWJkXCk%2BS8QIOZNThNeUYkxTTTArOKU1wQpXAqE7qTRUVVwWaNOE8uioIzskAhtMBEEh9QVG5SfEfK1hqUSbEkZEmgObxBilOWQKy7eGsf9hB%2F25S%2Ftl8gzXmeE0Fy6LguDYNC%2FdXDFagJwfXr1Wocx%2BVr74Jd7u2wcjLoLvQrF2S1Ct7Itp8YvmRYdjWWzmkIKyt9jXVXL5twbEHYeVu%2FqlCGk4uTjrp66OsDFGo9GKXL0dShiSukIrnTRpt9EwDD0pE6D3EK0Wi62o4fui71id66OM2BPl7nhvw3ZM9e1voo%2FSGCnwC2j%2BV3OZaPtjXqVG67nZ0KLzC%2B9R%2FJZpCmLb%2B2WgVvO6PKT%2BatfDrdlLrQlhsVzGCC0TN91n0wR9udyientWpuhcrbsddxo8%2BNt0f9IAqgNpZ%2FSAWh1zvt%2FeUEZL0J8cvd%2FseEwKQzxVfqLkaFoLVKtrEHvH2%2BGarIUgaGymZDCc5mR7l2chS5208kDCyc0dl%2B7H56mE7Tf9G%2BbguW%2BJ%2B28%2Fkv',
    '_ga_CD30TTEK1F': 'GS1.1.1615866089.1.1.1615866100.0',
    '_gat': '1',
}
        self.headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'ADRUM': 'isAjax:true',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    'Origin': 'https://ptab.uspto.gov',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Referer': 'https://ptab.uspto.gov/',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
}
    def login(self, url):
        with requests.Session() as r:
            response = r.post(url, headers=self.headers, params=self.params, cookies=self.cookies, data=self.data).url
            print(response)
# After this line the code should perform steps 2 and 3 described above

ptab = ptab()
ptab.login('https://ptab.uspto.gov/ptabe2e/rest/login')
```

Comment: Is the search tab just a `<form>` on the page?  If so, you just have to send a POST request to the URL in the `<form>` tag, supplying values for the fields.

Comment: The fact that there is a `rest` in the URL suggests that they have an API designed for programs like this to use, without faking requests.  Have you investigated that?